# Set cursor in the first on TextInput always kivy

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

Someone know how can I set the cursor on the first line in kivy after enter?

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        BoxPrincipal = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')

        self.textinput = TextInput(text='Hello world', multiline=False)
        self.textinput.bind(on_text_validate=self.on_enter)

        BoxPrincipal.add_widget(self.textinput)


        return BoxPrincipal

    def on_enter(self, instance):
        print('User pressed enter in', instance)
        print self.textinput.cursor_row
        self.textinput.text = ""
        self.textinput.focus = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

After enter I need to set the cursor in the first on TextInput

Someone can help me?

Comment: after adding parentheses around your second print statement in the on_enter method. your textinput clears and adding another print statement print(self.textinput.cursor) your cursor is at (0, 0). What are you really trying to achieve? Could you add some more background to your question.

Comment: and enter refers to pressing the enter key not entering textinput. Did you get that mixed up?

Answer (score 0):

[image]
[image]
Setting your cursor to the first position and having a text in TextInput before entering can be achieved easier.  There is a Property called `hint_text` see here https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.hint_text

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        BoxPrincipal = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')

        self.textinput = TextInput(hint_text='Hello world', multiline=False)

        BoxPrincipal.add_widget(self.textinput)


        return BoxPrincipal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I need that after writing something in TextInput and giving an enter, the action "on_text_validate" is executed and then the cursor returns to the position (0,0) of the TextInput